# SQL Return a Value depending on 3 ranges of dates

Tags: t-sql, sorting, date, validation, datetime

I am having issues sorting some dates in 3 different ranges of dates and return a values according to the correct range. I am hoping you can give me a efficent and clean way of doing it.

I have 6 different dates that I get from a SQL Table. Those dates are then stored in variables. All the dates can also be a Null value. My dates are seperated in 3 date ranges. I want to return an indication of what ranges I am in by using the earliest start Date in all of my ranges. The date of the correct range must also be smaller than the current Date. A date Range can also consist of only an End Date. In that case, we considered that the range end at the end date and is active before that. We select the earliest end date that is close to the current Date in that case.

Return 0 if all the date are null

Range #1(Category #1) X Start Date and X end Date  Return 1

Range #2(Category #2) Y Start Date and Y end Date  Return 2

Range #3(Category #3) Z Start Date and Z end Date  Return 3

EDIT

```
Ex#1 XStart = December 10 , XEnd = December 15  
     YStart = December 12 , Yend = December 13  
     ZStart = December 9 , ZEnd = Null 

Expected result would be Z Category

Ex#2 XStart = December 8 , XEnd = December 15  
     YStart = NULL , Yend = NULL  
     ZStart = December 9 , ZEnd = Null  

Expected result would be X Category

Ex#3XStart = NULL , XEnd = December 15  
   YStart = NULL , Yend = NULL  
 ZStart = December 9 , ZEnd = Null  

Expected result would be X Category

Ex#4 XStart = December 10 , XEnd = December 15  
    YStart = NULL , Yend = NULL  
    ZStart = December 9 , ZEnd = Null  

Expected result would be Z Category
```

Is there a more efficent way than doing a lot of IF statements ? I am having difficulty handling all of those conditions and checks. Here is a snippet of what I have so far.

```
    --Return 0 is not Condition is Applicable

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HO_GetReason] 
    @HOID INT   
AS
BEGIN

Declare @IsHOIDReal INT = (SELECT ID from T_HO where id = @HOID)
Declare @XStartDate Datetime 
Declare @XEndDate Datetime 
Declare @YStartDate Datetime 
Declare @YEndDate Datetime 
Declare @ZStartDate Datetime 
Declare @ZEndDate Datetime 

CREATE TABLE #tmpT_HO_Withhold (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    XStartDate Datetime null,
    XEndDate Datetime null,
    YStartDate Datetime null,
    YEndDate Datetime null,
    ZStartDate Datetime null,
    ZEndDate Datetime null,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
)

IF (@IsHOIDReal IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tmpT_HO_Withhold
    SELECT T_HO.ID, 
    XStartDate ,
    XEndDate ,
    YStartDate ,
    YEndDate ,
    ZStartDate ,
    ZEndDate
    FROM dbo.T_HO
    WHERE ID = @HOID

    SET @XStartDate = (Select TOP 1 XStartDate from #tmpT_HO_Withhold)
    SET @XEndDate = (Select TOP 1 XEndDate from #tmpT_HO_Withhold)
    SET @YStartDate = (Select TOP 1 YStartDate from #tmpT_HO_Withhold)
    SET @YEndDate = (Select TOP 1 YEndDate from #tmpT_HO_Withhold)
    SET @ZStartDate = (Select TOP 1 ZStartDate from #tmpT_HO_Withhold)
    SET @ZEndDate = (Select TOP 1 ZEndDate from #tmpT_HO_Withhold)

    IF(@XStartDate IS NULL AND @YStartDate IS NULL AND @ZStartDate IS NULL)
    BEGIN  print 'NO CONDITION' Select 0 as 'HO_GetReason'  END

    ELSE IF (@XStartDate IS NOT NULL AND @YStartDate IS NULL AND @ZStartDate IS NULL) BEGIN print '1' Select 1 as 'HO_GetReason'END

    ELSE IF (@XStartDate IS NOT NULL AND @YStartDate IS NULL AND @ZStartDate IS NULL) BEGIN print '2' Select 2 as 'HO_GetReason'END

    ELSE IF (@XStartDate IS NULL AND @YStartDate IS NULL AND @ZStartDate IS NOT NULL) BEGIN print '3' Select 3 as 'HO_GetReason'END

END
DROP TABLE #tmpT_HO_Withhold END
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help. They ought to clarify the confusion between "using the earliest start Date in all of my ranges" and checking X, then Y, then Z dates in that order and using the first match as the result without comparing start dates. And "must also be smaller than the current Date" without any comparisons to the current date? If multiple start dates are null (or in the future) then how do you pick a result, e.g. the earliest end date >= today?

Comment: I uodated my question with some exeamples of what I am trying to do. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Notes regarding efficient and clean:

Complex conditional are not in the inefficient category.  It can fall into the hard to read category and maintain, but they are a pretty quick operation.

- Example: That second "else if" looks strangely like the first "else if".   Code will not be reached.

Creating and destroying the temp table will be the slowest part of your stored procedure.

- Temp tables using #tablename are not concurrency safe in stored procedure, you can end up with odd schema altered errors in some cases.

You can get to the same results by swapping most of that with:

```
SELECT 
    @XStartDate = XStartDate ,
    @XEndDate = XEndDate ,
    @YStartDate = YStartDate ,
    @YEndDate = YEndDate ,
    @ZStartDate = ZStartDate ,
    @ZEndDate = ZEndDate
FROM dbo.T_HO
WHERE ID = @HOID
```

Id is unique based on the primary key spotted in your create table, so TOP isn't necessary in this format, no rows will leave the values as null.

---

Personally, once I get that conditional working (absolute final form), I would be tempted to directly adjust it to a CASE statement and set that as a PERSISTENT computed COLUMN in the base table.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T_HO ADD Reason AS (CASE WHEN XStartDate IS NOT NULL AND ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE 0 END) PERSISTED
```